# Looking for vowels (in phoneme tier, 2) within specific words(in word tier, 1) in Praat textgrid

Tags: praat

How can I extract specific vowels in a phoneme tier within a word in the word tier? I'm not sure how to limit my search to just the words I found previously in the word tier. Is it possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the Linguistics StackExchange

You (or someone you work with that is familiar with praat scripting) should be able to accomplish this with 
a praat script.

The following script should be easily adapted to fit your needs. In fact, on line 60 you can see that it asks the user for a targets file which would be the words that you have already identified. Assuming you have a p2fa-like aligned text grid.

https://github.com/jmriebold/Praat-Tools/blob/master/Arpabet-Vowel-Analyzer.praat